# Camera not panning closer to the object

Tags: camera

[image]

I am following a blender guru tutorial of making a doughnut but for some reason, I can`t zoom closer to see the doughnut and this picture given below shows how close I can come to the doughnut.

Answer (score 1):

Select the object that you want to zoom into and then press the 'period or full stop' key on your keyboard.

The key is located under the '3 Pgdn' key and left to the enter button.

[image]